# Ansible EC2 Module to Retrieve information about the Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I see the Ansible EC2 Module's capability to provision / start / stop / terminate. However is there a way to lookup / query for the instance details like `Private IP`, `Public IP` etc.

I am looking at the use case to obtain the Public IP [not the Elastic IP] which keeps changing during stop/start and update the Route53 DNS records accordingly.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you mean you are using Ansible to start an instance and then want to update the Route53 record with the new public IP address of the instance? Can you share what you're currently doing?

Comment: Yes - thats exactly what I want to automate. The problem what I am facing is that - due to the variation in launch time - I am able to obtain the public _ip after register / debug the result only occasionally [ it returns IP sometimes and other wise a null - meaning the instance is starting state ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set ***wait: True***? It will wait for the instance to go to running state. I never had issues with the following. I was able to get the public IP after register. If you still have issues, use **wait_for** for IP to be available. Or post your script here.

```
- name: Start the instance if not running
  ec2:
    instance_ids: myinstanceid
    region: us-east-1
    state: running
    wait: True
  register: myinst
```

Answer (score 2):

You can register the new boxes to an ec2 variable and wait for them to get private and public IPs, and then access them like so:

```
- name: provision new boxes
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Provision a set of instances
      ec2:
        group: "{{ aws_security_group }}"
        instance_type: "{{ aws_instance_type }}"
        image: "{{ aws_ami_id }}"
        region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        vpc_subnet_id: "{{ aws_vpc_subnet_id }}"
        key_name: "{{ aws_key_name }}"
        wait: true
        count: "{{ num_machines }}"
        instance_tags: "{{ tags }}"
      register: ec2

    - name: Add all instance public IPs to public group
      add_host: hostname={{ item.public_ip }} groups=new_public_ips
      with_items: ec2.instances

    - name: Add all instance private IPs to private group
      add_host: hostname={{ item.private_ip }} groups=new_private_ips
      with_items: ec2.instances
```